# Duplicate console log

Tags: node.js, console.log

I'm not sure why but this line of code (towards the bottom)

```
console.log(user_location);//this prints out 2 console responses
```

within this code

```
    var net = require('net');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

// require request-ip and register it as middleware
var requestIp = require('request-ip');

// to convert the ip into geolocation coords
var geoip2 = require('geoip2');

// you can override which attirbute the ip will be set on by
// passing in an options object with an attributeName
app.use(requestIp.mw({ attributeName : 'myCustomAttributeName' }));

// respond to all requests
app.use(function(req, res) {

    // use our custom attributeName that we registered in the middleware
    //var ip = req.myCustomAttributeName;
    var ip = '207.97.227.239';
    //console.log(ip);
    //console.log('requestip ip is:  ' + ip);

    // https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_isip_input
    var ipType = net.isIP(ip); // returns 0 for invalid, 4 for IPv4, and 6 for IPv6
    res.end('Hello, your ip address is ' + ip + ' and is of type IPv' + ipType + '\n');

    //geoip2
    geoip2.init();// init the db
    //console.log(ip);
        geoip2.lookupSimple(ip, function(error, result) {//67.183.57.64, 207.97.227.239
            var user_location = result.city;
          if (error) {
            console.log("Error: %s", error);
          }
          else if (user_location) {//replaced result with user_location
            console.log(user_location);//this prints out 2 console responses
          }
        });
});
```

I'm not sure why its printing the `user_location` twice in the console... I'm somewhat new to nodejs... so I'm not sure why this is happening... can someone with more knowledge of nodejs can point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Put a `console.log` statement in each nested block, and see what gets invoked twice. You may find that the middleware is running twice, for example

Comment: @slezica yea I think your right, its got something to do with the mw. Ill keep testing and post back if I solve it. Thx!